# Need Explaination : Adding Two Binary Numbers in Java

Tags: java

Can anyone please explain this code?
Programme: How to add two binary number.
explain below the asterix sign

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Exercise17 {

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
long binary1, binary2;
int i = 0, remainder = 0;
int[] sum = new int[20];
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Input first binary number: ");
binary1 = in.nextLong();
System.out.print("Input second binary number: ");
binary2 = in.nextLong();

while (binary1 != 0 || binary2 != 0) 
{
```

---

> **// explain code below
>       // what does %10 means?
>       // why %2?**

```
sum[i++] = (int)((binary1 % 10 + binary2 % 10 + remainder) % 2);
remainder = (int)((binary1 % 10 + binary2 % 10 + remainder) / 2);
binary1 = binary1 / 10;
```

> **// why to divide by /10?**

```
binary2 = binary2 / 10;
}
if (remainder != 0) {
sum[i++] = remainder;
}
--i;
System.out.print("Sum of two binary numbers: ");
while (i >= 0) {
System.out.print(sum[i--]);
}
System.out.print("\n"); 
}
}
```

Comment: What do C or C++ have to do with your question?

Comment: Why tag c and c++?

Comment: Please format your code properly. The binary operators are covered in every basic tutorial, e.g. [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html). As to the semantics  of the program... why not ask the author or do a pen&paper test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%10` means remainder of division by 10.
`%2` is remainder of division by 2.
`/ 10` is basically shift by one digit.

Imagine you have two "binary" numbers `101` and `110`. `%10` will get you the last digit for each of the numbers (`1` and `0`). Then you sum these digits and `%2` gets you the digit of the sum.

The best way to understand the code is to run it in a debugger.

Comment: Thank You so much, just needed to know why %10 and now i know (to get the last digits), to get the remainder of the sum %2 being used instead of this can't i use %10?